# Why is the GridBagLayout forcing some height on my components?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have the following code to display a number of labels in a panel :

```
    private static class Bordered extends JLabel {
        public Bordered(final String text) {
            super(text);
            this.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.BLACK));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("toto");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(new Bordered("0"), new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("1"), new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("2"), new GridBagConstraints(2,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("3"), new GridBagConstraints(1,1,1,2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("4"), new GridBagConstraints(2,1,1,2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("5"), new GridBagConstraints(3,2,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("6"), new GridBagConstraints(4,0,1,3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("7"), new GridBagConstraints(3,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("7bis"), new GridBagConstraints(3,1,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));


        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
    }
```

As it is everything works fine :

[image: Layout]

Now, I don't really have a use for 7 and 7bis, I just added them to show you what I want. So lets remove them :

```
    private static class Bordered extends JLabel {
        public Bordered(final String text) {
            super(text);
            this.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.BLACK));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("toto");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(new Bordered("0"), new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("1"), new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("2"), new GridBagConstraints(2,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("3"), new GridBagConstraints(1,1,1,2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("4"), new GridBagConstraints(2,1,1,2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("5"), new GridBagConstraints(3,2,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
        panel.add(new Bordered("6"), new GridBagConstraints(4,0,1,3, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
//        panel.add(new Bordered("7"), new GridBagConstraints(3,0,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));
//        panel.add(new Bordered("7bis"), new GridBagConstraints(3,1,1,1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3), 0, 0));


        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
    }
```

Now I get this monstrosity :

[image: Monstrosity]

The height on number 3 and 4 are no longer taken into account, everything is of same height.

Why is this happening ? How can I force the layout to obey me :( ?

Comment: Put blank JLabels into the 7 and 7bis positions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is neither a solution nor an explanation though. I shouldn't have to put random artifacts in my components.

Comment: But this is how GridBagLayout works. For a greater detailed explanation, please search for the hundreds of similar questions on this site. Thanks for criticizing someone trying to help you for free.

Comment: The layout is now actually honouring the heights of your components.  The fact they were taller is because `3` and `4` were made to fill two rows and fill in the horizontal direction. The real question here is, why would you expect them to remain "over sized" after you changed the conditions of the layout - I'd agree with HovercraftFullOfEels, if you're after the "effect" then a "filler" component would help achieve your desired result

Comment: What happens when you don't invoke `frame.pack();`?

Comment: @BhalchandraSW: which he *should* do regardless, so your comment is a non-starter.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Number 5's contract is to be 1 by 1 and at the 3rd row. This contract is clearly NOT being followed by the layout here. How can number 4 and number 5 have the same height, or even be in the same position, when their y and height attributes are different ?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry if I sounded aggressive. I meant to say that, while your solution would work, it is more of a hack. My real case is much more complex than this, and I have to manage a lot more panels, with completely different layouts and orderings. I can't just put a 1 by 1 label everywhere there might be a problem. How do I even recognize such a case?

Comment: Moreover, if I where to actually want #7 and #7bis as one single component taking a height of 2, I would get the same kind of bug, where 7 would be of same size as #5 even though they have different height. Doesn't seem like a feature to me.

Comment: @Saffron It's not a bug, this is just how `GridBagLayout` works - it might not make sense to you, but `GridBagLayout` is very complex layout which needs to make sense of a lot of possible scenarios, so it places precedence on certain conditions, row/column spanning isn't high on that list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Number 5's contract is to be 1 by 1 and at the 3rd row. This contract is clearly NOT being followed by the layout here. How can number 4 and number 5 have the same height, or even be in the same position, when their y and height attributes are different ?

You have somewhat of a misunderstanding in how `GridBagLayout` works

So, your original layout looks something like this...

[image: Original]

Cells `1x1` (`3`) and `2x1` (`4`) are actually oversized, their heights are a sum of the heights of rows `1` and `2`

Then you remove the cells at `3x0` and `3x1` and you have the expectation of something like this...

[image: Expectations]

But, wait, `GridBagLayout` is clever, it's deduced that, because of the row spans, row 1 is actually empty (has a combined size of 0) so it compresses the row and you end up with...

[image: Actual]

You might think this is "wrong", but it's not, and it takes some time to think about what's actually happening.

The only cell which is actually has any affect on the height of row `1` is cell `3x1`, which technically now has a size of `0`, because nothing resides there, so the row height becomes, `0` (also the preferred height of the cells @ `1x1` and `1x2` are smaller than the sum of the two rows the span from before, it has an affect as well)

So `GridBagLayout` looks at cells `1x1` (`3`) and `2x1` (`4`) and calculates their heights as a sum of the heights of rows `1` and `2`, but because `0` plus anything is anything, the row is "collapsed" and `GridBagLayout` relies on the `preferred/minimum/maximum` size of the components to determine the actual height to be used.

Now, I know, you're going to complain that this doesn't make sense, because cells `1x1` (`3`) and `2x1` (`4`) start in row `1`, and their height should affect the height of the row and everything, in some sense they do, but then they also expand two rows, which in the mind of `GridBagLayout` has an effect on the outcome, this is just how `GridBagLayout` works.

So, what's the solution? Like it or not, if you want the layout NOT to compress, you need to supply some kind of component at `3x2` which has the desired height of the row.  I know, it's not a great solution and I've done a lot of different hacks in the past to make it work (using a `JLabel` whose foreground color was the same as the background color of the container, or which had a foreground color which was completely transparent. I've even used my own layout manager which ignored the `visible` property of the component to cause it to keep the container at the the same size, so I could "hide" and "show" the component without having the layout compress)

Another solution might be to investigate other layout managers, I recommend MigLayout as a starting point.

Now, again, before you complain about it "not making sense" or "not be right" or "it must be bug" - Remember, this is how `GridBagLayout` has worked for the past 20+ years - this is how it works - you need to understand it and work with it or find an alternative - sorry to be a pain about that, but that's just the way it is :(

Comment: I second the use of 3rd party layout managers where the layout requirements are "stressing" the standard ones. Another solution is to delve into creating a custom layout manager. 1+